# What is the difference between these two java statements?

Tags: java, oop

I've been learning java programming recently and I am quite confused between these two statements.

```
System.out.println("Hello, world");
System.console().printf("Hello, world");
```

I know that `out` is a `static` variable of **`System`** class and `printf()` is the method of `Printstream` class.

But I am not getting the second statement. I know a little bit of OOP . So if **`System`** class has a method like `console()` then how can a method have methods like `printf()` ?

Comment: Because that method returns an object, which has other methods.

Comment: You already got many good answers, so i feel safe giving this one: I compared the two lines via `compareTo()` and it said the difference was `12`.

Comment: Very clever. Though I didn't know the method until I searched google

Comment: @mumpitz you can compare but you can't get any difference between the statements since `"System.out.println(\"Hello, world\");"` cannot be cast to `Integer`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `console()` method doesn't have a method like `printf()`, it *returns an object* that has a `printf()` method. Specifically, the [`console()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console--) returns a [`Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) object.

This pattern is called [*method chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

> So if **`System`** class has a method like `console()` then how can a method have methods like `printf()` ?

`System.console()` returns a `Console` object, and you're invoking the `printf()` method on that `Console` object.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The `console()` method returns an instance of `Console` object.

You can rewrite it like this:

```
Console console = System.console();
console.printf("Hello, world");
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html for more details

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

From System javadoc :

> console()
>   Returns the unique Console object associated with the
>   current Java virtual machine, if any.

So console() method returns a Console object and `printf()` is a method of class Console

`System.out.println()` on the other hand is calling `println()` method on the static PrintStream field "out" of class System

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Java statements and method calls are evaluated left to right. System has a method [console()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) which grants access to the console associate with the JVM. You are now working the object representing the console of the JVM when you call the method printf(). printf() is a method of the console of the JVM, not System itself.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot